# Upscale/downscale 1-dimensional signal in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have time series data that is represented in two lists, i.e.:

```
dataDomain = [-10.20, -10.01, -9.97, -9.85, -9.68]
dataMeasured = [2.3, 7.3, 1.5, 4.4, 5.0]
```

Each measured value corresponds to the domain value at the same list index position (dataMeasured = f(dataDomain)).

Now I want to upscale/downscale the signal. The domain should consist of n equally-spaced intervals, which can be achieved with the method 'linspace' from the numpy library:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
newDomain = np.linspace(min(dataDomain), max(dataDomain), n)
```

So far, so good.

But, in order to assign for each domain value a measured data value, I need to average the measured data for the intervals along the domain. Is there a neat way to do so?

Comment: Could you share the expected output?

Comment: Okay, it is very fiddly to create the expected outcome. Basically, what I want to do is to up-/downscale a timeseries (= 1-dimensional signal).

Comment: [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is your library for 1D time series